# Regex to match character string with none to multiple hyphens

Tags: php, regex

Hi I need to match a character string which can have 0+ hyphens in between the characters. I'm using PHP preg-match to do this. The characters can be upper or lowercase. Here's a few examples:

```
TESTTESTtest published successfully
test-TEST-test published successfully
Test-test published successfully
```

My regex needs to capture all these different cases.

I am going through a log line by line and trying to match the regex below to each line.

This is my current if statement:

```
if(preg_match('/(\w*) published successfully/',$line,$matches){

}
```

I just used \w* as my character capture as I didn't need to worry about hyphens before but I need to adapt this to handle the new scenario. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you please explain what you are doing and why `expode("-", $s)` does not work?

Comment: Hi I've added additional information to my initial question, not sure how I would use explode in this instance but I probably didn't have enough information provided before.

Comment: Good, haven't you thought of character classes? Like `[\w-]*`? Do you have to worry about cases like `------ published successfully`?

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly thank you, I don't really know much about regex I'm working off someone else's code so I was struggling to adapt it, I had tried something like ([\w-*]) and it wasn't working but I was clearly typing it out wrong. Thanks so much, I don't need to worry about the edge cases you mentioned what you provided is fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to worry about edge cases like `----- published successfully` all you need is to add the `\w` and `-` to a **character class** `[...]` (and I also suggest using a `+` quantifier to match 1 or more occurrences, not 0 or more, to avoid getting empty matches):

```
if(preg_match('/([\w-]+) published successfully/',$line,$matches){

}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4fBnVL/2).